# Running OpenCL on CLion in Windows with NVIDIA

Tags: windows, dll, linker, opencl, clion

I am attempting to compile and link a C/C++ OpenCL application in CLion on Windows using the NVIDIA OpenCL library provided in the [NVIDIA CUDA 7.5 SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

My issue is that CLion is using CMake and the Cygwin GCC compiler to create code in Windows. Therefore, there is some confusion about whether I should use the .lib, the .a, the .dll, or the .o files during runtime.

There is an indication is that I may be able to export definitions from `OpenCl.dll` and create  `opencl.a` to import and potentially run against `OpenCl.dll`. Cygwin has [this guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) for using `nm` for linking against DLL's. They indicate that we may do

```
echo EXPORTS > foo.def
nm foo.dll | grep ' T _' | sed 's/.* T _//' >> foo.def
dlltool --def foo.def --dllname foo.dll --output-lib foo.a
```

will create work. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185955/compile-opencl-on-mingw-nvidia-sdk) contains instructions on how to complete the task with MinGW and also uses dlltool.

However, as the cygwin guide warns, the running `nm OpenCl.dll` from the OpenCl.dll in the NVIDIA CUDA SDK results in `nm: OpenCl.dll: no symbols` indicating that the DLL has been stripped or some error has occurred.

I am working with the CUDA 7.5 SDK but suspect the issues will be similar across the board.

Has anyone successfully built and linked in CLion for Windows, or from Cygwin in a Windows Environment?

Comment: nVIDIA ships only stripped versions. You need to get the defs in another way, nm does only use debug data, so it is a logical result that it does not work.

Comment: @DarkZeros Agreed. Is it known how to acquire a stable def file? My thought is that there is a high probability that the core opencl function defs should be transferable but I am unsure about compatibility issues with transferring between cygwin and windows, possible name mangling (?), etc.

Comment: While I don't have experience with Cygwin, I have used the libOpenCL.a file from the AMD APP SDK when building code in MinGW-w64. Hopefully you can use libOpenCL.a too. I haven't had issues using this on NVIDIA GPUs so long as I stick to the OpenCL version they support (1.1 on older drivers, 1.2 on newer drivers).